# Why are they not wearing safety belts while driving an armoured truck?

Tags: realism, wrath-of-man

In this movie ***Wrath of Man***, when Bullet is informing H that their truck will be jacked soon and warn H not to resist; I noticed Bullet is not wearing his safety belt.

I am wondering if this scene is realistic for an armour truck driver to not wear the safety belt while driving.

The reasons I can think of are:

- They need to make frequent stops so that it is more convenient for them to not put on the belt
- They are trained to not to wear it in high risk areas as wearing it stops them from reacting faster

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting - my first thought was that seat belt usage would be low in the USA, but that seems to be based on old data. Apparently usage is about 90% nowadays.

As for the reasons why they don't use seatbelts in the van - it very likely is due to experience and preference. Back in my days in the reserves, whenever we were in combat (training) conditions, we wouldn't wear seat belts as we would have to be able to bundle out of the vehicle quickly depending on the situation.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, seatbelts are mandatory, at least for the front seats, in most places in the US these days. I believe more people think seatbelts save lives than in the past, and some people simply want to avoid a ticket.